# How to get xpath of custom check box in native ios app appium

Tags: appium-ios

I'm having difficulty getting the attributes of custom check box in a native iOS app.

I tried using Appium inspector and ISO automation. In Appium inspector it's giving the Xpath but that's not working related to the check box.

[image: Appium Inspector]

In ISO automation I'm able to get only the co-ordinates of the check box "target.tap({x:48.50, y:372.00});"

[image: ISO Automation]

Comment: have u tried using driver.tap() method?

Answer (score 0):

I've been learning new things about appium these days
theres a few things you can try, I will post the answer in ruby, but its pretty the same in java:

`find_element(:id, 'I accept').click`

Im pretty sure [touch action](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/TouchAction.java) will work for you

`Appium::TouchAction.new.tap(x: 48, y: 372, count: 1).perform`

`execute_script(UIATarget.localTarget().tap({x:48, y:372})`

I dont know much about instruments automation, but I know theres no way to use the code it generates on your test, and apple is discontinuing it